# gnuplot operation of multicolumn file while iteration

Tags: awk, gnuplot, iteration

I'm using gnuplot to plot a file with many columns:

```
plot for [i=2:119]  "./file.dat" using 1:i w l lt  9
```

It works fine, BUT I'm not able to edit it in order to print the lines shifted.
I'd like to print this, where N is a the shift value

```
plot for [i=2:119]  "./file.dat" using 1:$i+N w l lt  9
```

but I receive the error( with the ^ on the $):

```
   gnuplot> plot for [i=2:119]  "./file.dat" using 1:$i+1 w l lt  9
    "./file.plt", line 182: Column number expected
```

A work around is to use AWK but also in that case I'm having some errors.

Answer (score 3):

To stay closest to your current script, you can do it as follows

```
 plot for [i=2:119]  "./file.dat" using 1:(column(i+N)) w l lt  9
```

I hope it is self-explanatory, but `gnuplot help using` provides some more info on `column()`

Answer (score 1):

I find that it gets tricky to remember how to do operations on column numbers which are stored as variables, or if it is even possible.  There are two workarounds, though:

1) Change your range

```
plot for [i=(2+N):(119+N)] "./file.dat" using 1:i ...
```

2) Use an intermediate variable

```
do for [i=2:119] {
    ii = i + N
    plot "./file.dat" using 1:ii ...
}
```